# Can highcharts heatmap zone pattenObjects respect colors applied by color axis?

Tags: svg, highcharts, heatmap

I'm trying to meet a style requirement for highcharts heatmaps. Currently, we style 'incomplete' data with a highcharts pattern fill by applying zones to x axis.

the chart currently looks like this, with the pattern fill applied to the zones on the right:
[jsfiddle heatmap with incomplete zones](http://jsfiddle.net/d54s8bxf/1/)

config for color axis:

```
colorAxis: {
   dataClasses: [
      {to: 3.33325, name: "<3.3", color: "#FFC4FF"},
      {from: 3.33325, to: 5, name: "3.3 to 5.0", color: "#FF70FF"},
      {from: 5, to: 6.66675, name: "5.0 to 6.7", color: "#D500F9"},
      {from: 6.66675, to: 8.33325, name: "6.7 to 8.3", color: "#550075"},
      {from: 8.33325, name: ">8.3", color: "#330046"},
  ]
}
```

series:

```
series: {
   data: {
      [
         {x: 0, y: 0, z: 1},
         {x: 0, y: 1, z: 2},
         {x: 0, y: 2, z: 3},
         {x: 1, y: 0, z: 4},
         {x: 1, y: 1, z: 5},
         {x: 1, y: 2, z: 6},
         {x: 2, y: 0, z: 7}
         {x: 2, y: 1, z: 8}
         {x: 2, y: 2, z: 9}
      ]
   }
   zones: [
      {value: 2},
      {
         color: {
            pattern:
            {
               backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC",
               height: 45,
               path: {
                 d: "M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,45 l45,-45 M44,46 l2,-2", 
                 stroke: "#FFFFFF",
                 strokeWidth: 3
               }
               width: 45
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Right now the pattern fill is gray for all of them but I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to set up the config so the background color will respect the color set by dataClasses. I tried setting it to currentColor, but the colorAxis color isn't applied to the parent element so that didn't work. I'm trying to avoid using classNames/styled mode if possible
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Hi @JBerbert91, Could you provide me with a minimal live example in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi, @ppotaczek,
here's a working demo... right now i have the svg fill hard-coded to gray, but i would like to be able to have the fill color change based on the colorAxis.

http://jsfiddle.net/d54s8bxf/1/

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to opt out of zones and change how colors for points are generated by overwriting `translateColors` method:

```
(function(H) {
    H.Series.prototype.translateColors = function() {
        var series = this,
            points = this.data.length ? this.data : this.points,
            nullColor = this.options.nullColor,
            colorAxis = this.colorAxis,
            colorKey = this.colorKey;

        points.forEach(function(point) {
            var value = point[colorKey],
                color;

            color = point.options.color ||
                (point.isNull ?
                    nullColor :
                    (colorAxis && typeof value !== 'undefined') ?

                    (
                        point.x < 2 ?
                        colorAxis.toColor(value, point) : {
                            pattern: {
                                backgroundColor: colorAxis.toColor(value, point),
                                height: 45,
                                width: 45,
                                path: {
                                    d: "M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,45 l45,-45 M44,46 l2,-2",
                                    stroke: '#FFFFFF',
                                    strokeWidth: 3
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ) :

                    point.color || series.color);

            if (color) {
                point.color = color;
            }
        });
    }
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lygwz16j/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: thanks @ppotaczek, can you tell me where to find the original highcharts code for this function?

Comment: Hi @JBerbert91, Sure: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/parts-map/ColorSeriesMixin.ts#L96